# Qt Signals and Slots Confusion

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have been reading about Qt signals and slots and I am trying to get this to work, but until now without success. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
I have two files, `homeCommand.cpp` and `messagelogcommand.cpp`. I have a `QPlainTextEdit` object in `messagelogcommand.cpp` that I want to update from `homeCommand.cpp`.
How can I do this using signals and slots? My signal is being called, as my QDebug is being printed out once a second, however the widget does not update.

This is what I am trying to do:

In MessageLogCommand.h

```
class MessageLogCommand : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MessageLogCommand(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QLabel *homeLabel;
    QPlainTextEdit *messageLog;

public Q_SLOTS:
    void updateWidgets(const QString &text);

};
```

homeCommand.h

```
class homeCommand : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

Q_SIGNALS:
    void textChanged(const QString &text);

public:
    explicit homeCommand(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void run(void);
    void getHealthStatusPacket(void);
```

homeCommand.cpp

```
homeCommand::homeCommand(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    //Timer
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(false);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(run()));
    timer->start(1000);

    setLayout(layout);
}

void homeCommand::run(void)
{
    getHealthStatusPacket();
}

void homeCommand::getHealthStatusPacket(void)
{
    ...
    Q_EMIT textChanged("ZOMG");
}
```

In MessageLogCommand.cpp

```
 MessageLogCommand::MessageLogCommand(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
 {

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
    QWidget::setFixedHeight(600);

    //Sub-system Label
    homeLabel = new QLabel("GSS Message Log");
    QFont subsystemFont = homeLabel->font();
    subsystemFont.setPointSize(12);
    subsystemFont.setBold(true);
    homeLabel->setFont(subsystemFont);
    layout->addWidget(homeLabel, 0, 0);

    //Event Log
    messageLog = new QPlainTextEdit();
    messageLog->setFixedHeight(500);
    messageLog->setFixedWidth(600);
    layout->addWidget(messageLog, 2,0);

    setLayout(layout);
}

void MessageLogCommand::updateWidgets(const QString &text)
{
    qDebug() << "Here";
    messageLog->appendPlainText(text);
}
```

In main.cpp

```
MessageLogCommand s;
homeCommand m;

QObject::connect(&m, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), &s, SLOT(updateWidgets(QString)));
```

Comment: I think for anyone to be of help, you need to provide what code you have in a ```code``` block

Comment: Show us more. Maybe there's no need to use signals&slots

Answer (score 2):

A very basic example is:

```
class MainClass:public QObject    //class must be derived from QObject!
{
   Q_OBJECT    //this macro must be in the class definition
               //so the moc compiler can generate the necessary glue code

   public:
       void doSomething() {
           ...
           Q_EMIT textChanged(someText);
       }

   Q_SIGNALS:
       void textChanged(const QString &text);
};

class SubClass:public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public Q_SLOTS:
       void onTextChanged(const QString &text) {    //do not inline
           //do something
       }
};

int main()
{
    QApplication a;

    MainClass m;
    SubClass s;
    QObject::connect(&m, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
                     &s, SLOT(onTextChanged(QString)));  //const and & are removed from
                                                         //the arguments

    return a.exec();    //run the event loop
}
```

So, there are 2 things important:
1. Signals and slots must be declared in a class derived from QObject
2. The classes containing signals and slots declarations must add the Q_OBJECT macro to the class declaration

To keep it simple for you: always declare your classes containing signals or slots in a header file (never in a .cpp file).

Comment: I tried this. It compiles, and I know the "onTextChanged" function is being called because I have a qDebug() message print out everytime it is called. For some reason my widget doesn't update though. It just stays blank. I even tried to just put a hardcoded string in and it never shows up. Idea's why this could be?

Comment: Could you give us more insight into your code, including class declarations?

Answer (score 0):

A very good starting point for signals and slots is: http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html but also the official Qt doc does it: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Basically what happens: you declare some special methods (signals and slots), at the compilation phase Qt generates extra CPP files which take care of your methods (moc) then everything is compiled and linked together and at the end when Qt or someone else emits a signal it will go to the corresponding slot.

Comment: I have read this documentation and still not not fully understand, I updated my original post with what I am attempting to do...

Answer (score -1):

I try to explain it.

In main.h you should to declare a signal:

```
signals:
     void textChanged(const QString& text);
```

And in messagelog.h you should to declare a slot:

```
public slots:
     void updateWidgets(const QString& text);
```

In main.cpp you should emit this signal:

```
void TheMethod() {
    emit this->textChanged("Your text/value");
}
```

In messagelog.cpp you should get this value:

```
// Note: Normalized signal/slot signatures drop the consts and references.
connect(&a, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(updateWidgets(QString)));

void updateWidgets(const QString& text) {
   messageLog = new QPlainTextEdit();
   messageLog->setFixedHeight(500);
   messageLog->setFixedWidth(600);
   messageLog->setPlainText(text)
   layout->addWidget(messageLog, 2,0);
}
```

I think it should works.

**UPDATE:**
Complete example: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29647980/test.zip

Comment: I am not sure if it right. It's quite a while ago since I have programmed for the last time in C++ an Qt.

Comment: Yes. You should do it for example in constructor.

Comment: The code complies and runs, but my updateWidgets() is never being triggered. I put a printf() statement in and nothing ever gets printed out.

Comment: @user2494298 you don't need to write `main::textChanged()` in connect, the scope comes from the object `textChanged(const QString&)` is good.

Comment: Because of some error in my code above I written an example, you can download it here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29647980/test.zip
It is easier to write complete code than parts of it. :)

Comment: @leemes, notice that Qt has its own garbage collection system. And some objects *may* big enough to make the stack overflow. While usually using `new` and `delete` for dynamically allocating memory is discouraged, in Qt it is often encouraged by the same Qt documentation.

Comment: @Jefffrey No, Qt does not have its own garbage collection. And dynamic allocation is not encouraged for `QString`, only for QObject-derived classes. I guess you thought about the QObject tree which is not garbage collection but a different kind of automatic memory management. And it only works if you tell each object its parent.

Comment: @leemes, a garbaged collection [is by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) an automatic memory management. Can you please tell, which "kind" of automatic memory management, the Qt's one, is or are you referring to?

Comment: @Jefffrey If we both mean the same thing in Qt, it's the parentship of QObjects. But you have to manage them (i.e. setup useful parents) manually to get a good result. Also, this obviously doesn't work for dynamic allocated objects not derived from QObject, as it is this class which manages the tree object. I don't call it garbage collection because it's not fully automatic and it's not working for general objects (like `QString` here). A typical (good) GC doesn't require any "help" as well as it can cope with any types. But this discussion is now off-topic as the answer has been edited.

Comment: @sharbag: If you think of answering, you don't really want to be posting the answer on another site, and you don't really want to post code that doesn't work if it's for a newbie that can be derailed by the simplest of things. Do your homework when working on an answer, misleading answers are pointless. -1 until you put an [sscce](http://sscce.org) here, instead of dropbox. It should be the contents of *one file*, the implied `main.cpp`. Put `#include "main.moc"` at the end.